# how does upvar work in " foreach parArray $parArrays {upvar $parArray $parArray}"

Tags: tcl

I come across this code ( part ) from VLT sequencer script

```
proc cnoseqImgAcqMoveToPixel {parArrays obsInfo} {    
   foreach parArray $parArrays {upvar $parArray $parArray}
   ...
}
```

I wonder if someone can tell me what the purpose of `{ upvar $parArray $parArray}` is.

Answer (score 1):

There's not quite enough information to be absolutely sure, but I can venture a guess. I'm guessing that `parArrays` is a list of array variable names and those array variables are in the scope of the caller of `cnoseqImgAcqMoveToPixel`. The `foreach` loop then iterates through the list of array variable names and calls `upvar`. The `upvar` command takes the name of a variable somewhere up the call stack (one level up in this case) and creates a local variable that references it. In this case, the local variable name is made the same as the array variable name that is passed in. The net effect is to take a list of array variables that are in the callers scope and make them into local variables of the same name.

In Tcl, arrays are really collections of variables indexed by a string and they cannot be passed by value. So the use of `upvar` is an idiom to pass an array by reference. In this case it appears like a set of arrays is being accessed by reference.

Comment: many thanks Andy. I understand what you said, but still puzzled why it uses  " upvar $parArray $parArray" . I  can understand " upvar $parArray local".   I tried  "set parArrays [list abc cde def this that] " and the foreach loop does not work, it has " Error: bad level "abc". is parArrays set wrongly?  thanks for your time

Comment: The use of "upvar $parArray $parArray" has the effect of giving the local variable the same name that the variable has in the caller. Otherwise, you would have to make up new local variable names which is probably more confusing. It's hard to be certain of the intent. BTW, I always call "upvar" with an explicit level, just to be safe, in this call would appear as "upvar 1 $parArray $parArray".

Comment: Jerry and Andy sorry for the later reply, I was away. Many thanks. Jerry's example explained it clearly what Andy was telling me.